# C++ Use a pointer where a pointer-to-pointer is expected

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I would like to extend a base class which has a virtual function that takes a pointer to an array of a type. The derived class is more complex and could take advantage of multiple pointers to an array of that type.

`derived` and `other` show different solutions to deals with that problem, but I dislike both of them. Is there anything I could do instead?

```
struct base {
    virtual void set(int* p, std::size_t n) { }
};

struct derived : base
{
    virtual void set(int* p, std::size_t n)
    {
        int** pp = new int*[1]; // must be deleted before destruction
        pp[0] = p;
        set(1, pp, n);
    }

    void set(std::size_t count, int* const* pp, std::size_t n)
    {
    }
};

struct other : base
{
    virtual void set(int* p, std::size_t n)
    {
        m_helper[0] = p;
        set(1, m_helper, n);
    }

    void set(std::size_t count, int* const* pp, std::size_t n)
    {
    }

private:
    int* m_helper[1];
};
```

Comment: I really understand neither your question nor your examples. Can you explain what your actual goal is?

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, if you don't want to save the pointer itself, this should do:

```
virtual void set(int* p, std::size_t n)
{
    set(1, &p, n);
}

void set(std::size_t count, int* const* pp, std::size_t n)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code  doesn't say anything about *the goal* which you want to achieve, as every function is *almost* empty. So I cannot suggest anything better than to use the following:

- Use `std::vector<int>` where you want to use `int*`
- Use `std::vector<std::vector<int> >` where you want to use `int**`

Answer (score 0):

You could use variable argument lists:

```
void set(std::size_t count, std::size_t n, ...) {
  va_list v;
  va_start(v, n);

  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
  {
    int* value = va_arg(vl, int*);
    // ...
  }

  va_end(v);
}
```